# C# Polly async-await: Wait for user confirmation before retry

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, polly

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS and Android where I am keeping data and a local sqlite database and online in an Azure server.  Although my app requires an internet connection which it is always checking with the Connectivity plugin, I've found that I will sometimes have an exception thrown if a user loses cell reception mid request.

I want to have a method I can call all my server requests to that will retry the request if an error occurs. I would also like the ability to ask the user for input before retrying.  The flow would look like this:

Call to server --> Exception Caught --> Ask user if they want to retry --> Retry

I found the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) package which is setup to handle try/catch retries in C#.  I currently have my code setup like this:

```
public class WebExceptionCatcher<T, R> where T : Task<R>
{      
    public async Task<R> runTask(Func<T> myTask)
    {
        Policy p = Policy.Handle<WebException>()
        .Or<MobileServiceInvalidOperationException>()
        .Or<HttpRequestException>()
        .RetryForeverAsync(onRetryAsync: async (e,i) => await RefreshAuthorization());

        return await p.ExecuteAsync<R>(myTask);
    }
}
```

My `RefreshAuthorization()` method simply displays a `DisplayAlert` on the current page on the main thread:

```
private async Task RefreshAuthorization()
{
    bool loop = true;
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Connection Lost", "Please re-connect to the internet and try again", "Retry");
        loop = false;
    });

    while (loop)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100); 
    }
}
```

When I debug this and cut my internet connection.  The `DisplayAlert` is never shown.  One of two things happens:

1. The execution continues to call my task over and over without completing
2. A `System.AggregateException` is thrown with the following message:

> System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Does anyone know how to successfully pause execution when a Task fails, and wait for the user to resume?

**UPDATE:**

After putting the call to `DisplayAlert` inside of the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method, I now have found a way around the `AggregateException`.  However, now I have another problem.

Once I disconnect from the internet, the `DisplayAlert` pops up like it is supposed to.  The program waits for me to click retry before finishing the `onRetry` function so the `RetryForeverAsync` waiting is working correctly.  The issue is that if I reconnect to the internet and then hit retry, it fails again, and again, and again.  So even though I'm connected to the internet, I'm stuck in an infinite loop of being asked to reconnect.  It seems that `RetryForeverAsync` is simply re-throwing the old exception.

Here is how I'm calling `runTask()`:

```
Task<TodoItem> t = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().LookupAsync(id);
WebExceptionCatcher<Task<TodoItem>, TodoItem> catcher = new WebExceptionCatcher<Task<TodoItem>, TodoItem>();
```

I've then tried two different ways of calling runTask, both with the same result of failing the retry when connection is re-established:

```
TodoItem item = await catcher.runTask(() => t);
```

or:

```
TodoItem item = await catcher.runTask(async () => await t);
```

Comment: Thanks, Have you tried `RetryForeverAsync`?

Comment: Yeah, that was actually what I was calling when I got the AggregateException

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.RetryForeverAsync(...)` as a commentor noted.  Then, since your on-retry delegate is async, you also need to use `onRetryAsync:`.  Thus:

`.RetryForeverAsync(onRetryAsync: async (e,i) => await RefreshAuthorization());`

---

To explain the errors you saw: In the code sample in the question, by using `onRetry:`, you are specifying that you want to use a synchronous `onRetry` delegate (returning void), but then assigning an async delegate to it.

That causes the async-delegate-assigned-to-sync-param to become `async void`; calling code doesn't/*can't* wait for that.  Since the `async void` delegate isn't waited for, your executed delegate would indeed be continuously retried.

The `System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed` could be caused by that, or could be caused by some mismatch in the signature of `myTask` (not available in the q at the time of posting this answer).

**EDIT** in response to **UPDATE** to question and further comments:

Re:

> It seems that RetryForeverAsync is simply re-throwing the old exception.

I know (as the Polly author/maintainer) that Polly certainly calls the passed `Func<Task<R>>` each time round the loop, and will only rethrow whatever exception that fresh execution of the `Func<Task<R>>` throws.  See the [async retry implementation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/8570720145a1846f89ad011fe2df3a132abe1b63/src/Polly.Shared/Retry/RetryEngineAsync.cs): it [retries the user delegate afresh](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/8570720145a1846f89ad011fe2df3a132abe1b63/src/Polly.Shared/Retry/RetryEngineAsync.cs#L31) each time round the [retry loop](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/8570720145a1846f89ad011fe2df3a132abe1b63/src/Polly.Shared/Retry/RetryEngineAsync.cs#L25-L58).

You could try something like the following (temporary, diagnostic) amendment to your calling code, to see if `RefreshAuthorization()` is now genuinely blocking the calling policy code from continuing execution, while it waits for the user to click retry.

```
public class WebExceptionCatcher<T, R> where T : Task<R>
{      
    public async Task<R> runTask(Func<T> t)
    {
        int j = 0;
        Policy p = Policy.Handle<WebException>()
        .Or<MobileServiceInvalidOperationException>()
        .Or<HttpRequestException>()
        .RetryForeverAsync(onRetryAsync: async (e,i) => await RefreshAuthorization());

        return await p.ExecuteAsync<R>( async () => 
        {
            j++;
            if ((j % 5) == 0) Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                 await DisplayAlert("Making retry "+ i, "whatever", "Ok");
            });
            await myTask;
        });
    }
}
```

If `RefreshAuthorization())` is blocking correctly, you will need to dismiss the `Connection Lost` popup five times before the `Making retry 5` dialog is displayed.

If `RefreshAuthorization())` is not blocking the calling code, the policy would have continued making multiple (failing) tries in the background before you reconnected and first dismissed the `Connection Lost` dialog.  If this scenario holds, then dismissing the `Connection Lost` popup just once, you would then see popups `Making retry 5`, `Making retry 10` (etc; possibly more), before the next `Connection Lost` popup.

Use this (temporary, diagnostic) amendment should also demonstrate that Polly is executing your passed delegate afresh each time.  If the same exceptions are being thrown by `myTask`, that may be a problem with `myTask` - we may need to know more about it, and dig deeper there.

---

**UPDATE** in response to originator's second update starting "Here is how I'm calling `runTask():`"

So: you have been assuming retries are failing, but you have constructed code that doesn't actually make any retries.

The source of the remaining problem is these two lines:

```
Task<TodoItem> t = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().LookupAsync(id);
TodoItem item = await catcher.runTask(() => t); // Or same effect: TodoItem item = await catcher.runTask(async () => await t);
```

This only ever calls `App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().LookupAsync(id)` once per traversal of these lines of code, regardless of the Polly policy (or equally if you had used a hand-built `while` or `for` loop for retries).

A `Task` instance is not 're-runnable': an instance of `Task` can only ever represent a single execution.  In this line:

```
Task<TodoItem> t = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().LookupAsync(id);
```

you call `LookupAsync(id)` just once, and assign into `t` a `Task` instance that represents that LookupAsync running and (when it completes or faults) the outcome of that one execution.  In the second line you then construct a lambda `() => t` that always returns that same instance of `Task`, representing that one execution. (The value of `t` never changes, and each time the func returns it, it still represents the result of that first-and-only execution of `LookupAsync(id)`.).  So, if the first call fails because there is no internet connection, all you have made the Polly retry policy do is keep `await`-ing a `Task` representing that first-and-only execution's failure, so the original failure indeed keeps getting rethrown.

To take `Task` out of the picture to illustrate the problem, it's a bit like writing this code:

```
int i = 0;
int j = i++;
Func<int> myFunc = () => j;
for (k=0; k<5; k++) Console.Write(myFunc());
```

and expecting it to print `12345` rather than (what it will print, the value of `j` five times) `11111`.

To make it work, simply:

```
TodoItem item = await catcher.runTask(() => App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().LookupAsync(id));
```

Then each invocation of the lambda will call `.LookupAsync(id)` afresh, returning a new instance of `Task<ToDoItem>` representing that fresh call.

Comment: This still throws the `System.AggregateException`.  I'll update the question to include my entire class

Comment: A ran it another time and got a different Exception: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: @cvanbeek Not familiar with that particular Android exception.  Let me know however if the switches to `async` Polly usage provide the necessary waiting (when other exceptions are fixed)

Comment: I got around the AggregateException which was being thrown because I was calling DisplayAlert off the main thread.  Now I have an issue that even when I reconnect to the internet, the retry fails.  See the update above for more info.

Comment: Did you switch to `onRetryAsync:` as my answer suggested?  If not, many of the effects described in the UPDATE to the q can be attributed to that (I can explain in detail).  You _must_ use `onRetryAsync:` to ensure that `RefreshAuthorization()` blocks the policy thread from proceeding until `RefreshAuthorization()` exits.  If this is not clear, read up on the perils of `async void` in event handlers / delegates.  Many blogs, eg: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andy_wigley/2013/07/31/beware-the-perils-of-asyncawait-in-application-lifecycle-event-handlers-in-fact-in-any-event-handlers/

Comment: Yes I am using `OnRetryAsync`. I apologize, I forgot to edit that part of my question.

Comment: The method is now waiting for me to press retry, but even when internet connection is reestablished the call to my web service fails.

Comment: If `RefreshAuthorization()` is correctly blocking the calling code, could the `myTask` you pass in be failing to detect the reconnected internet connection?  Or could the instance of `myTask` passed in not be amenable to repeated invocation? - be just returning the same original result?

Comment: _Note_: In the code posted so far, you don't use the variable `t`, and `myTask` is not defined: are they the same thing?  It could also be helpful to see the nature of the `Func<Task<R>>` typically passed in.

Comment: yes, I appoligize, `t` and `myTask` were the same thing, I changed one to try to make the question more clear and forgot to change the other.  I have made that fix to the question and also have now shown both ways I've attempted to call `runTask()`.  Also, `RefreshAuthorization()` is correctly blocking the calling code.

Comment: You could also consider using `Device.InvokeOnMainThread()` rather than `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`, if available.  At least in the monotouch documentation, it indicates that `Device.InvokeOnMainThread()` blocks until the action on the main thread completes, whereas `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` only queues it for the main thread and returns immediately to the caller (does not block).  With `Device.InvokeOnMainThread()`, you may be able to omit everything you around using the `bool loop` variable to ensure blocking.